# Implementing a QR Code reader for Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qr-code

I have seen a lot of stuff out their for implementing a QR decoder such as ZXing which I will probably use to process the decode process.  But I am already using PHPQRCode to create QR codes.  The next step I am trying to take is okay, if someone is on my site.  They can click scan and it would open the Android camera and scan the QR code.

I am not to sure on if ZXing will open the camera for you or if it just decodes the code from a scanner.  Let me know what you guys think, and if you know of anything that I could check out.

I was hoping to stay towards using HTML5/JQuery or anything that is web basesd.

David

Comment: you can take a picture with <input>, but you'de probably have to send the image data off to an api to parse it into a qrcode's data package...

Comment: Ya I was hoping for a active scanner, I actually figured it out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode it is port of zxing to javascript.